# How can I get only the selected inputs to be processed in multiple forms?

Tags: php, shopping-cart

How can I get only the selected inputs to be processed in multiple forms? `isset()`?... I want "shoppers" to choose which quantities of each "style" they want and click submit.
LINK: http://taketwodesigns.com/monkeypod/order/index.php
 They are then be sent to the confirmation page and will email that page. I will have many item styles with up to 6 sizes each. I have each item style in a separate form currently(and it submits fine). 
I tried to use only 1 form for submitting multiple styles, but that didn't work because I am using the "Required" attribute. 
When I submit only 1 style, It shows "Required" for any fields that are not selected..(When using single form approach)
Submitting only 1 form is great with me! Thanks!

```
<form action="process/process_mlv101_207bk.php" method="post" name="orderform1" class="margins">
    <a href="images/styles/large/mh800bk_big.jpg" target="_blank"><img class="thumb_align" src="images/styles/thumbs/mh800bk_thumb.jpg" /></a>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr class="gridaddrows">
            <td colspan=8 class="radius">
                <span class="formtext"><b>You must click the "Add to Cart" button to place items in cart.</b></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gridrows">
            <td class="gridtitle">Add</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">XS</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">S</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">M</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">L</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">XL</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">2XL</td>
        </tr>
        <td class="add_to_cart_btn">
            <input type="image" src="../order/images/clicktoadd83pxfast.gif" alt="Add to Cart" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mlv101_207bkxs" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mlv101_207bksm" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mlv101_207bkmd" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mlv101_207bklg" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mlv101_207bkxl" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mlv101_207bkxxl" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
    </table>
</form>
<!----------- 2ND STYLE BELOW ---------------->
<form action="process/process_mmt101_107bk.php" method="post" name="orderform1" class="margins">
    <a href="images/styles/large/mmt101-107bk_big.jpg" target="_blank"><img class="thumb_align" src="images/styles/thumbs/mmt101-107bk_thumb.jpg" /></a>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="1">
        <tr class="gridaddrows">
            <td colspan=8 class="radius">
                <span class="formtext"><b>You must click the "Add to Cart" button to place items in cart.</b></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gridrows">
            <td class="gridtitle">Add</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">XS</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">S</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">M</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">L</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">XL</td>
            <td class="gridtitle">2XL</td>
        </tr>
        <td class="add_to_cart_btn">
            <input type="image" src="../order/images/clicktoadd83pxfast.gif" alt="Add to Cart" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mmt101_107bkxs" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mmt101_107bksm" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mmt101_107bkmd" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mmt101_107bklg" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mmt101_107bkxl" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" name="mmt101_107bkxxl" placeholder="Qty" min="0" max="288" required autocomplete="off">
        </td>
    </table>
</form>

<!------------ 3RD STYLE BELOW etc... ------------>

<!-----------PHP BELOW ---------->

<?php

$mlv101_207bkxs  = $_POST['mlv101_207bkxs'];
$mlv101_207bksm  = $_POST['mlv101_207bksm'];
$mlv101_207bkmd  = $_POST['mlv101_207bkmd'];
$mlv101_207bklg  = $_POST['mlv101_207bklg'];
$mlv101_207bkxl  = $_POST['mlv101_207bkxl'];
$mlv101_207bkxxl = $_POST['mlv101_207bkxxl'];

if(isset($_POST['mlv101_207bkxs'],
         $_POST['mlv101_207bksm'],
         $_POST['mlv101_207bkmd'],
         $_POST['mlv101_207bklg'],
         $_POST['mlv101_207bkxl'],
         $_POST['mlv101_207bkxxl'] )){    

$mlv101_207bkxs  = ltrim($mlv101_207bkxs, '0');
$mlv101_207bksm  = ltrim($mlv101_207bksm, '0');
$mlv101_207bkmd  = ltrim($mlv101_207bkmd, '0');
$mlv101_207bklg  = ltrim($mlv101_207bklg, '0');
$mlv101_207bkxl  = ltrim($mlv101_207bkxl, '0');
$mlv101_207bkxxl = ltrim($mlv101_207bkxxl, '0');

    echo '<p class="great">Thank you for your order!</p>';

    echo "<ul><h3>Ordered Items Below</h3><h4>Item# MLV101-207BK</h4>";

    echo "<li>" . $mlv101_207bkxs .  "&nbsp; -&nbsp; X-Small" . "</li>";
    echo "<li>" . $mlv101_207bksm . "&nbsp; -&nbsp; Small" . "</li>";
    echo "<li>" . $mlv101_207bkmd . "&nbsp; -&nbsp; Medium" . "</li>";
    echo "<li>" . $mlv101_207bklg . "&nbsp; -&nbsp; Large" . "</li>";
    echo "<li>" . $mlv101_207bkxl . "&nbsp; -&nbsp; X-Large" . "</li>";
    echo "<li>" . $mlv101_207bkxxl . "&nbsp; -&nbsp; XX-Large" . "</li>";

    echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You could have default value in each field as 0 or you can remove required property and check when form is submitted that at least one field in form is entered.

Comment: And I don't know why are you using different action urls for every item when you can use one PHP file to process any item. As you add more and more items it's gonna be a pain in the ass to keep adding them. Not to mention if you find a bug or wish to add some functionality in code, you will have to fix every file.

Comment: "Pain in the ass avoided renders a man happy" :) I need to avoid any any item Qtys from being rendered on page after submit. How about 'isset()' ?  Just have the items selected rendered? Of course then I need to keep the items quantities separate...

Comment: You should array the inputs in your form(s). You will make it cleaner and easier to work with.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. It's good to have a separate action url for processing submits. I've seen too many questions on this site with people cluttering their php code logic with html. What I meant is that every form on your order page can have same/one action url for processing.

Comment: TheDrot... I do think it's good to have only one action url for processing, The user will be submitting: SM, MD, LG, XL, XXL Qtys for one style, and SM,  LG,  XXL for another.... My processing script works good for just one style,.... Like Rasclatt said, it may be best with arrays. As in my code, I need to process all sizes of one style at one time and render that on a separate page as an order. How can I simplify the processing of 6 inputs at one time? And maybe up to 80 inputs at one time.... :)